# JMock context error

Tags: java, junit, jmock

I've set up a JMock context in my JUnit @Before test, something like:

```
context.checking(new Expectations()
 {
   {
    allowing(mockPayload).getContent();
    will(returnValue(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(XML_FILE)));
   }
});
```

This reads in an xml file and does some tests on it's content. Later on in the test I want to read in a different file and do similar tests. Is there anyway to do this without creating a new 'context', ie, by re-using the context to read in a different file. I know that Junit doesn't guarantee the order of the tests you carry out, so trying to reuse a context that might not have been used yet is going to cause an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Sharing context in unit tests usually indicates there is code smell.

Comment: You could write a method to setup the expectations based on parameters like the file to use.